# C# Creating Base Class to Write to CSV file with differnt headers, while reading from an Object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm repetitively new to OOP and C#. I need to create a Base Class (which a few other sub-classes can use and add some additional properties), that will do following:
1. Read Property from class Customer (i.e. Name, Age, Job, Country), and add those as a Headers into CSV file.
2. Take values for each of those properties, taken from the Command Line, and assign accordingly.
3. Add those values into the same CSV file, accordingly to the Headers Column.

I know have part to set Headers:

```
using (StreamWriter output = File.CreateText("AS_DataStoreOut.csv"))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(output))
{
      csvWriter.WriteHeader<Customer>();
      csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
```

I have part to take value from CMD and assign (the number of parameters and the order can be different for different customers - might get new property for a Business Customer etc.):

```
public static Customer EnterValues(Customer customer)
{
    Console.Write("What is your Name?: ");
    customer.Name = (Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("What is your Age?: ");
    customer.Age = (Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("What is your Job?: ");
    customer.Job= (Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("What is your Country?: ");
    customer.Country= (Console.ReadLine());

    return customer;
}
```

But how now to add those into the same CSV file, and make sure those are entered in the correct order (based on the Header already there)?

Comment: You need to do `csvWriter.WriteRecord<Customer>(customer)`;

Comment: Thanks folks! The linked question helps to solve my question. I can delete my question if needed.